# thick fieldset rounded border around legend

Tags: html, css

I need to make the fieldset borders which are attached to the legend look rounded. what is the easiest way of doing it using css?

```css
fieldset {
 text-align: center;
 border: 20px solid;
 border-radius: 50px;

}

legend {
 width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> <span>title</span></legend>
    <p>data goes here </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use box-shadow to add the curve

```css
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

legend {
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> <span>title</span></legend>
    <p>data goes here </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove legend tag and try this html code.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
   <span>title</span>
    <p>data goes here </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```